# Javascript spread operator for depth-first search

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use spread operator `...` to append item to an array in depth-first search. However, it shows weird behaviour:

- with `array.push()`, the array is correct: ['a','b','c','d];
- with `[...array, this.name]`, the array is different each time.

For example: if the `search()` function is called recursively for a tree like this:

```
   A
  /\
 B C
/
D
```

with spread operator, the `log` looks like this:

```
array = []
this.name = A
array = [A];
=====
array = [A]
this.name = B
array = [A,B]
=====
array = [A,B]
this.name = D
array = [A,B,D]
====
array = [A] // not [A,B,D]
this.name = C
array = [A,C]
```

with `push()`, the `log` looks like this:

```
array = []
this.name = A
array = [A];
=====
array = [A]
this.name = B
array = [A,B]
=====
array = [A,B]
this.name = D
array = [A,B,D]
====
array = [A,B,D]
this.name = C
array = [A,B,D,C] // expected
```

```js
class Node {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.children = [];
    }

    addChild(name) {
      this.children.push(new Node(name));
      return this;
    }

    search(array) {
        console.log('this name:');
        console.log(this.name);
        console.log('array before:');
        console.log(array);
        // array.push(this.name);
        array = [...array, this.name];
        console.log('array after');
        console.log(array);
        for (let child of this.children) {
            child.search(array);
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not ask a question. At least you need to explain what "the array is different each time." exactly means.

Comment: I get the same array every time. Could you provide working example to reproduce, please?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear the first time. I've added more details.

Comment: Spread syntax is more correct in this case (your `push` implementation works just by accident): sharing data in recursion algorithms is a recipe for a disaster. So `array = [A,C]` - this is perfectly expected, you iterate every node independently. If you want to merge results - you must merge it manually, as in every other recursive algorithm. `child.search(array);` <--- here you ignore the returned result, but instead must handle it (eg merge)

Comment: @zerkms. I've tried this ```let c = [...array, this.name]; for (let child of this.children) { child.search(c); } return c;``` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Viet I'm not sure what that code means, you must use the `child.search(c)` result, not throw it away. Eg: `array = array.concat(child.search(c))`

Comment: @Viet in your updated comment you again ignore the value `child.search(c);` returns.

Comment: @zerkms Since I'm not sure what's wrong with the spread operator, can you elaborate why the `push()` works by accident? Doesn't it append the current name of the node to the array, then each `child.search(array)` calls the search with the *updated* array?

Comment: @Viet there is nothing wrong with it, it's your code that ignores the result returned by `child.search(c)` is wrong. "why the push() works by accident?" --- because it mutates the same array. You need to be very careful with recursive algorithms and the shared state: generally the idea is that every branch works with its own part of the state.

Comment: @zerkms above you wrote "Spread syntax is more correct in this case (your push implementation works just by accident)". What did you mean by that? It sounds like `push()` isn't supposed to work.

Comment: @Viet either would work fine as long as you fix a bug in **your** code: you must not ignore the result returned by a `child.search(c)` call and every branch of a recursive algorithm should work with its own copy of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't in whether you use the spread operator or `array.push()`, it's simply that your implementation relies on the **same instance** of your search array being passed to all nodes, but every time you run `array = [...array, this.name]` you're creating a **new array instance** that is now disconnected from all of the parent search arrays.

To elaborate, `array.push()` *mutates* `array` - it is still the same array instance, just with new contents. But `array = [...]`, regardless of what's in the array literal, is creating a new array with new contents - the reference to the old array, the one passed to the `search()` function by the node's parent, is discarded. All further modifications to `array` will not be known by the node's parent.

Because you need to modify the same array instance in each search function, you simply need to either use `array.push()` and not spread, or pass an object containing `array` to each function so that each branch's nodes can access the same array instance regardless of if it's been reassigned.

Comment: Thank you @Klaycon. Your answer makes sense. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Like why `push()` maintains the *updated* array and `spread operator` doesn't?

Comment: @Viet because `.push` by definition mutates the same array. And a new array operation `[... ]` creates a new array.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @Viet I've edited the answer with further details, but zerkms seems to have covered it already. Glad it's cleared up for you.